# How n (1+b) is not prime?

Tags: number-theory, primes

Here is the complete proof taken from [this](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-045j-automata-computability-and-complexity-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_045JS11_lec05.pdf) link

[image]

How do I convince myself that `n(1+b)` is not prime when b>=1?
Here is what I did:
if n is 3 and b is 3. Then resulting string 111 111 is prime. Is this how it should be done it in proofs? 
The way I see is this. If n(1+b) is not proved for even one set of values then I can say it is not prime. Set of values in this case was n =3 & b = 3.

Is this approach of understanding poofs is right?

Comment: [Crossposted](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1318192/17111) on [math.SE]. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration.

Comment: Since this is at heart a pure mathematics question, I'm closing as offtopic.

Answer (score 2):

$n(1+b)$ is not prime for any integers $n>1$ and $b\geq 1$, simply because it is divisible by both $n$ and $(b+1)$, and the conditions on $n$ and $b$ guarantee that neither of these factors is $1$.

Note that we must have $n>1$, since $n\geq p$ where $p$ is the number of states in an automaton which we suppose to exist that accepts the given language. Since a $1$-state automaton can only accept $\emptyset$ or $\Sigma^*$, we must have $p>1$.

Comment: If there is only one state in DFA then because of `n>=p`, n can be equal to 1. What happens then? Now at least one of factor is 1.

Comment: @user3461957 Good point. Edited.